# Apktool decompiling/decoding exception

Tags: decode, apktool

I want to recompile adidas app. When I use Apktool in Windows CLI, the exception is raised:

```
C:\Apktool>apktool d adidasConfirmed.apk
I: Using Apktool 2.2.2 on adidasConfirmed.apk
I: Loading resource table...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f090000 string/abc_act
ion_bar_home_description, config=-sr
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResType.addResource(ResType.java:66)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResType.addResource(ResType.java:55)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:270)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTableType(ARSCDecoder.java:226)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTableTypeSpec(ARSCDecoder.java:156)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTablePackage(ARSCDecoder.java:118)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTableHeader(ARSCDecoder.java:80)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:559)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:72)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:64)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:67)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.setTargetSdkVersion(ApkDecoder.java:193)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:102)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:166)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

What's wrong?

P.S. I've gotten this app from [here](https://apkpure.com/adidas-confirmed/com.gpshopper.adidas).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
apktool d adidasConfirmed.apk --keep-broken-res
```